# why I do not get my total count of a column with sum function in R?

Tags: r, sum

I have tried for already several hours to get a total count of one column using sum, in R. It worked in one case nicely but in this case it doesn't and do not understand why.

here it is a fake data set

```
fake_data <- structure(list(age_recoded_band = c("0-19", "20-39", "40-59", 
"60+"), country = c("India", "India", "India", "India"), count_age_country = c(921L, 
24601L, 11446L, 2561L), comorbidities = c("asthma", "asthma", 
"asthma", "asthma"), count_study_pop_comorb = c(27L, 570L, 330L, 
142L), comorbidity_rate = c(0.0293159609120521, 0.0231697898459412, 
0.0288310326751704, 0.0554470909800859), count_age_group_standard_pop = c(4772L, 
102286L, 55505L, 12827L), total_counts_stnd_pop = c(175390L, 
175390L, 175390L, 175390L), expected_comorb_study_pop = c(139.895765472313, 
2369.94512418194, 1600.26646863533, 711.219836001562)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), groups = structure(list(age_recoded_band = c("0-19", "20-39", 
"40-59", "60+"), .rows = structure(list(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I am applying the `sum` on `expected_comorb_study_pop` and do not get the answer I want

```
dt_total_expected_standard_pop <- fake_data %>%
  dplyr::mutate(total_expected_study_pop_comorb = sum(expected_comorb_study_pop))
```

I actually get the same result as in `expected_comorb_study_pop` which is wrong. The total is `4,819`.

Does someone know why `sum` function does not give me the output desired?

Comment: I have changed the code as the line in which total_standard_pop_age appears is not relevant to the problem I am trying to solve

Comment: Can you try on a fresh R session.  It is surprising as even with `dplyr::` you are getting that output as. I am getting grouped output

Comment: One thing I noticed is that there is only a single row per group (based on the dput).  So, you are getting the same value of that single value sum?

Comment: If you have a group attribute do , `fake_data %>% ungroup %>% summarise(total_expected_study_pop_comorb = sum(expected_comorb_study_pop))` or `mutate` if you need to create a new column

Comment: @akrun that worked nicely ! would you please put it as an answer. I feel ungroup is widely forgotten by us and this function is there with a clear reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a grouping attribute and there was only one row per group, resulting in the `sum` to return exactly that single value.  If we do `ungroup`, it will work

```
library(dplyr)
fake_data %>%
     ungroup %>%
     summarise(total_expected_study_pop_comorb = sum(expected_comorb_study_pop,
                  na.rm = TRUE))
```

`summarise` returns a single row.  If we need to create a new column use `mutate`